# How to get proper path in Java using JFileChooser as per the Operating system

Tags: java, path, jfilechooser

In my Java application I need to select a path using JFileChooser. The code that I have written is as follows:

```
jfChooser = new JFileChooser();

jfChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));

jfChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
if (jfChooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): "+  jfChooser.getCurrentDirectory());
System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : "+  jfChooser.getSelectedFile());
tfPath.setText(jfChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()); // the selected path set to textfield which is lated get by the program
}
else {
System.out.println("No Selection ");
}
```

I am getting the path properly.For example, here I am getting the path (In Windows os)

```
String choosedPath=tfPath.getText().trimm();
```

Now actually I want to create a another directory on a given path (i.e. inside newfolder directory) programatically.

For that I have new directory name "newdir" so the string passed to File constructor for creating this directory is as follows:

```
File createFolder = new File("choosedPath"+"\\"+"newdir");
```

Now the problem is that my application may run on windows or may run on Linux so according to that the filepath seperator varies (i.e. '/' for windows and '\' for linux)

How do I Overcome this problem so that I will get propper slashes in path according to OS?

Comment: you should consider checking out the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) and learning how to format your code for your next question

Comment: In Java you can use forward slashes on windows file paths and java will handle it. As others have said File.Seperator is the correct OS agnositc solution. You can get away with using a forward slash everywhere though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new File(choosedPath, "newDir");`

Platform dependent file separator gonna be choose automatically.

You can too use `File.separator` to get platform dependent separator to construct the string but you going to end with more code than first solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`File.separator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) instead of `/` or `\`.